# Upgrading from Symfony 2.6 to 2.7: In a ChoiceType, what does the "choices_as_values" do?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am currently upgrading a Symfony project from version 2.6 to 2.7. I am doing that using the [Symfony 2.6-2.7 upgrade guide](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.7.0/UPGRADE-2.7.md). It says:

> You should flip the keys and values of the "choices" option in ChoiceType and set the "choices_as_values" option to true. The default value of that option will be switched to true in Symfony 3.0.

I have done that. But my forms do not work as expected anymore: there are no default values set for any expanded choice fields anymore (ie with `expanded = true` and `multiple = false`). Before, with a field defined as:

```
$builder->add('handwork', 'choice', array(
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => array(
        1 => 'Yes',
        0 => 'No',
    ),
)
```

The `No` choice was selected by default (or was that because of a PHP cast from `''` or `null` to `0`?).

So I went to the [Symfony docs on the choice form field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#compound) to understand what `choices_as_values` does. But it is not documented there.

What am I doing wrong ? And how come this `choices_as_values` option is not documented?

**Edit 1:** After reading some more Github issues, it seems like the doc update is not yet ready, which would explain why I was not finding what I needed in the docs. It would seem that previously, in 2.6, my forms automatically casted empty values like `null` or `""` to `0`, which made them work as needed. I've yet to figure out how `null` or `""` ends up in my field.

**Edit 2:** It seems like adding the option `'choice_value' => function($v) { return $v; },` helps get back my default values. This is because in SF 2.7, the `value` attributes of `radio` inputs are generated from scratch. They are an integer instead the value provided in the `choices` array.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm upgrading a Sf site,  several choices with strings as keys and values  started to return integer values and also the default checked value get lost in other choices,  `'choice_value' => function($v) { return $v; }` was the solution!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to keep `'choices_as_values' => false`.

```
$builder->add('handwork', 'choice', array(
    'multiple' => false,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => array(
        1 => 'Yes',
        0 => 'No',
    ),
    'choices_as_values' => false
)
```

Changing it to 'true' introduces BC-break and is scheduled to v3. 
It's been added to handle more complex objects, and does not play well with arrays yet: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14377

Set default values in the form builder, e.g for default 'No':

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder(['handwork' => 0]);
```

Documentation update is due: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5179

Comment: Thanks for your help @Alex. In the example, you give, the values are not flipped, as described in the upgrade guide. Why is that ?

Comment: Because with `'choices_as_values' => false` `choices` is an array of `value => label` pairs. I just assumed you expect something like `<input type="radio" value="1" /><label>Yes</label>` on the page.